# how to relate string to object instances in java

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a code block where i deserialize incoming data and then i have to cast this into some known class object, so for that reason i do something like this:

```
   if (object instanceof MyClass) {
         Myclass data = (MyClass)object;  
   }
```

it works fine, however now i have a situation where there could be different type of calsses. So is there a way to do the comparison based on `"String"`:

```
   if (object instanceof "String") {
         String data = (String)object;  
   }
```

the problem is in this case, the user will specify the class object name, so how can i do that?
Should i force user to initiate a dummy object and then pass to my method or is there a way to initialize null object with String, any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a proper (de)serialization library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's smelly, ugly, and I don't like it, but you *can* use [`Class#forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Class#isInstance(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
if (Class.forName("java.lang.String").isInstance(object)) {
     String data = (String)object;  
}
```

You're still going to have problems with the cast, though. `Class#cast()` only gets you compile-time type safety when you've got a `Class<T>` – but you can only get a `Class<?>` from `Class#forName()`.

Comment: +1 especially for "smelly"; there is an article that I read recently saying "whenever you find yourself using the `instanceof`, stop and slap yourself". The right design with polymorphism should remove the need for this. Edit: here is the aricle on [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31)

Comment: I guess I am missing why OP has to cast as a string when object **appears** to be a valid Java object.

Comment: Thank you it works just fine in some test cases, @Woot4Moo, not necessarily string, here the custom object name will be specified as string, so it could be some custom class object passed but as String value.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Class#forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and [Class#isInstance(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29). to accomplish this

Heres a sample code

```
FileDemo dd = new FileDemo();
Class object = Class.forName("com.FileDemo");

if(object.isInstance(object)){
    //do your conversion
}
```

Comment: +1, exactly what i was looking for, same as Matt's answer but more elaborately explained

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```
if(object instanceof MyClass)  
{
             Myclass data = (MyClass)object;  
} else  
{  
       String data = object.toString();
}
```

By default every `Object` in java has a `toString` function that can be invoked.  There is no need to cast to a `String`

Comment: @MattBall I don't think I missed the point at all.  The question was how do I do an instanceof check against a String.  Which OP proceeded to use "String" (the literal) and instead could invoke the toString function.  But perhaps I am missing what you mean, care to expound?

Comment: "the problem is in this case, the user will specify the class object name, so how can i do that?"

Answer (score 0):

See the "forname" method here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html